# Редирект в .htaccess

Tags: редирект, .htaccess

Есть, к примеру, ссылки:

```
http://site.com
http://site.com/ru/
http://site.com/ru/add/
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при переходе на ссылку `http://site.com/ru/` переводило на `http://site.com`, но при `http://site.com/ru/add/` так и оставалась на этой же ссылке!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^/?ru([/]*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Изменил на: RewriteRule `^/?ru/$ /$1 [R=301,L]` - заработало. )))  
Видимо, все дело в том, у меня "/" добавляется к концу ссылки,  а если как ваш пример, то там зацикливание при URL: http://site.com/ru//

Comment: Можно и $1 из правила убрать в таком случае.